# Sound effect library management on Windows?

Tags: sound-effects, sound-libraries, metadata, database

I'm starting to have a little collection of various sound effects, and I was looking for a program to help me find them more easily than with iTunes or searching through Windows.

I know of [Basehead](http://www.baseheadinc.com/#basehead-overview) and [Soundminer](http://store.soundminer.com/product-tour/), but they are bit too expensive for me at the moment.

Preferably the solution should support adding/editing metadata, but that might be asking for a bit much considering the low cost option I'm looking for. As the title implied, I am using Windows (Win7 64bit to be exact.)

Do you have any programs to suggest to me or even a workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: Try FooSFX - it's a freeware program created with Foobar and some plugins. I've been working with it for several years and it does exactly what you need.
http://liquidblasted.net/foosfx/

Comment: Thank you so much! I've looked into it and downloaded it a few hours ago. The instalation process seems a bit... hard. Is it a pain to set up databases with it? Also, do you happen to know if there are any good tutorials for foosfx?

Comment: It doesn't need installation: just go File -- Preferences -- Media Library -- Add.. and select your SFX folders. Click Apply or OK and wait for some time until all your sounds are scanned and placed in the FooSFX database.
If you have any other questions, just read the readme.txt file in the program's folder.

Answer (score 1):

For lower budgets, Soundminer do the HD range, which works on both Mac and PC.

It's a fraction of the cost of the full Soundminer v4, and I highly recommend it if it's within your price range.

Answer (score 0):

Use Loopcloud Free. You can add your own sounds and meta data, and it’s easy to install and use. https://www.loopcloud.com/

Answer (score -2):

netmixle
I have not used but I know people who have installed and works great, I'll be installing it next week.
http://www.netmixle.com/

Comment: Thank you! I have been looking at their website and I could not find any info on the pricing. I've contacted them for a quote but was NetMix expensive?

Comment: I think netmix**LE** is free.